# Send logs to Cloudwatch from shell

Tags: docker, amazon-cloudwatch

Firstly, please don't get confused, I know how to setup ECS task definition to send the container logs to the Cloudwatch.

**The question is** that how can I send a log entry from inside the container to the `stdout` so presumably it will be sent to the Cloudwatch.

I simply logged into the container and ran, say `echo 'test' >&1` (and even `docker exec -ti <container-id> echo 'test' >&1`) and the only thing I saw was `test` as the output on my screen and it didn't go to the Cloudwatch. I guess that I'm not redirecting the output to the stdout used by `awslogs` driver correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So the approach (assumption) was correct, but the problem was that instead of `&1` I had to use `/proc/1/fd/1` (&1 i.e. stdout, is a simlink to `/proc/self/fd/1`).

So in case you want to send a log from inside your container to the container logs collector you can just simply try `echo test >> /proc/1/fd/1` and it should appear in the log group > log stream defined in the task definition of your container.